# How could I change the XAXIS value in plotly js to show me the date in another way?

Tags: javascript, mysql, plot, plotly, plotly.js

I have a select that selects the time in milliseconds passed to date using this sql statement:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT from_unixtime(dd.ts, '%D %H:%i'), 
                              dd.a_menos 
                       FROM dev_data dd, users u, users_dev ud 
                       WHERE u.id = ud.id_user 
                        AND ud.id_dev = dd.id_dev 
                        AND u.id = :id 
                        AND dd.ts BETWEEN :tsmin AND :tsmax");
```

It shows me the result like this:

As you can see the date looks a bit wrong

[image]

What I want to achieve is that in the XAXIS it shows only the days and when you increase the zoom of the graph you can see the hours, is it possible?

P.D.: My code -->

```
<?php
    require_once "connection.php";
    $dbh= connect();

    require "code.php";
    $tsmin=tsPrimerDiaMes(4);
    $tsmax=maxTs(4);
    $data = array('id' => 4, 'tsmin' => $tsmin, 'tsmax' => $tsmax);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT from_unixtime(dd.ts, '%D %H:%i'), dd.a_menos FROM dev_data dd, users u, users_dev ud WHERE u.id = ud.id_user AND ud.id_dev = dd.id_dev AND u.id = :id AND dd.ts BETWEEN :tsmin AND :tsmax");
    $stmt->execute($data);
    $valoresX=array();
    $valoresY=array();
    while($fila = $stmt->fetch()){
        $valoresX[]=$fila[0];
        $valoresY[]=$fila[1];
    }
    $datosX=json_encode($valoresX);
    $datosY=json_encode($valoresY);

?>
<div id="graficaLineal"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function crearCadenaLineal(json){
        var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
        var arr = [];
        for(var x in parsed){
            arr.push(parsed[x]);
        }
        return arr;
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    datosX=crearCadenaLineal('<?php echo $datosX ?>')
    datosY=crearCadenaLineal('<?php echo $datosY ?>')
    var prueba = {
        x: datosX,
        y: datosY,
        type: 'scatter',
        line: {
            color: 'blue',
            width:2
        }
    };
    var data = [prueba];
    var layout = {
        title: 'Generacion',
        plot_bgcolor:"lightblue",
        paper_bgcolor:"lightgreen",
        xaxis: {
            title: 'Dias',
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yaxis: {
            title: 'KW'
        }
    }
    Plotly.newPlot('graficaLineal', data, layout);
</script>
```